# Android, Multiple Tables, SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I have another problem with SQLite database in Android OS.
I'm trying to create database with two tables: departments and students.
Departments table contains: dep_id, dep_name and dep_major.
Students table contains: stud_id, dep_id, firstname, surname, email, phone.

How can I put data into this two tables?

There is a Databasehandler.java:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHandler";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "studentsManager2.db";

// pola tabeli "wydzial"
private static final String TABLE_DEPARTMENTS = "departments",
        KEY_DEP_ID = "id",
        KEY_DEPARTMENT = "wydzial",
        KEY_SPECIALIZATION = "kierunek";
// pola tabeli "students"
private static final String TABLE_STUDENTS = "students",
        KEY_STUD_ID = "id",
        KEY_ID = KEY_DEP_ID,
        KEY_FIRSTNAME = "imie",
        KEY_SURNAME = "nazwisko",
        KEY_INDEKS = "indeks",
        KEY_EMAIL = "email",
        KEY_NUMER = "numer";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DEPARTMENTS + "(" + KEY_DEP_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_DEPARTMENT + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_SPECIALIZATION + " TEXT NOT NULL)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_STUDENTS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_SURNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_INDEKS + " INTEGER," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_NUMER + " TEXT NOT NULL)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data.");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DEPARTMENTS);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_STUDENTS);
    onCreate(db);
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but `INSERT` is the SQL command for inserting data into a table.

Answer (score 0):

Below methods will insert the records in the sqlite database using Datbase helper class:

```
public void insertDataInBothTables() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues valuesForDepartmentTable = new ContentValues();
    valuesForDepartmentTable.put(KEY_DEPARTMENT , "name");
    valuesForDepartmentTable.put(KEY_SPECIALIZATION , "special");

    // insert row
    long idOfDepart = db.insert(TABLE_DEPARTMENTS, null, valuesForDepartmentTable);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, "first-name");
    values.put(KEY_SURNAME, "sur-name");
    values.put(KEY_INDEKS , "inserting-data");
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL , "inserting-data");
    values.put(KEY_NUMER , "inserting-data");
    //Parameter to add department id
    values.put(KEY_WYDZIAL, idOfDepart + "");

    // insert row
    db.insert(TABLE_STUDENTS, null, values);

}
```

Comment: and these two tables will be interdependent ?
when I add the student along with its data, and faculty and field of study is that the application should correctly read and write in the database ?

Comment: What do you mean by "interdependent"? Yes, these methods write the data correctly in database...!

Comment: What i mean is: if I click on saveButton to save data in database I need to call two methods, correct?and the databasehandler.class is ok?

Comment: I updated the answer, now you can call the above single method to write the data in both tables....! And yes, your class looks good...!

Comment: ok, thanks for help. I will check it tomorrow, it's too late for this. I will give info about job :)

Comment: Why are you using `dbCreate.getReadableDatabase();`, you should use `dbCreate.getWritableDatabase();`

Comment: An SQLiteConstraintException is thrown if one of the constraints is violated. In your case, all fields are constrained to be non-null. So, the error is caused by trying to insert a null value into one of those fields. Add some logging to find out which one it is.

Comment: yea, I changed 'dbCreate.getReadableDatabase();' to 'dbCreate.getWritableDatabase();' .

Comment: "wydzial" or "kierunek" one of these variables are containing empty or null value in your onClick() method...!

Please log both variables, you will get your solution...!

Comment: Where I should log them ?

Comment: Please log all your values("imie, nazwisko, indeks, email, wydzial, kierunek, telefon") in your `onClick(View)` method before `if statment`

Comment: Like this: `Log.v("SomeLabel", "imie to: " + etImie);` ?

Comment: Ok, I made the log variables, but not before if - in if statment

`10-18 20:39:16.287 21811-21811/? V/Variable: imie to: Name`
`10-18 20:39:16.287 21811-21811/? V/Variable: nazwisko to: Surname`
`10-18 20:39:16.287 21811-21811/? V/Variable: indeks to: 214563`
`10-18 20:39:16.287 21811-21811/? V/Variable: email to: email@dot.com`
`10-18 20:39:16.287 21811-21811/? V/Variable: telefon to: 236541236`
`10-18 20:39:16.288 21811-21811/? V/Variable: wydzial to: department`
`10-18 20:39:16.288 21811-21811/? V/Variable: kierunek to: major`

Comment: I checked database in DBManager in FireFox. Application is only adding variables into departments table not into students... :(

Comment: Error inserting email=ff numer=888 imie=tt nazwisko=ttt indeks=22 ::(

Comment: You are using two columns with same name in student table

Comment: KEY_DEP_ID = "id",
KEY_ID = KEY_DEP_ID

Comment: yy, no? KEY_STUD_ID = "id",
            KEY_ID = KEY_DEP_ID,

Comment: I thought that students table need id for students and id for departments

Comment: Brother, you have two columns in your table "students" named KEY_STUD_ID, KEY_ID...! And both containing the same values which is "id"

Comment: Your students table query `"CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_STUDENTS + "(" + KEY_STUD_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_SURNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_INDEKS + " INTEGER," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL," + KEY_NUMER + " TEXT NOT NULL)"`

Comment: @pank_94 use a different name for department id like "depart_id"

Comment: It's not working :( `private static final String TABLE_DEPARTMENTS = "departments",
            COLUMN_DEPARTMENT_ID = "_id",
            KEY_DEPARTMENT = "wydzial",
            KEY_SPECIALIZATION = "kierunek";
    // pola tabeli "students"
    private static final String TABLE_STUDENTS = "students",
            COLUMN_STUDENT_ID = COLUMN_DEPARTMENT_ID,
            COLUMN_STUDENTS_ID = "student_id",
            KEY_FIRSTNAME = "imie",
            KEY_SURNAME = "nazwisko",
            KEY_INDEKS = "indeks",
            KEY_EMAIL = "email",
            KEY_NUMER = "numer";`

Comment: The field COLUMN_STUDENT_ID is empty ... if i deleted this, dave to database works

Comment: It's necessary to have two variavles of ID for table students?

Comment: Yes, you need to change one of the column's name(Like: id, department_id) otherwise you can'r do that

Comment: Yea, I changed it. But it;s problem in id.  How I can make two columns with id's? 

`private static final String TABLE_DEPARTMENTS = "departments",
            COLUMN_DEPARTMENT_ID = "_id",
            KEY_DEPARTMENT = "wydzial",
            KEY_SPECIALIZATION = "kierunek";
    // pola tabeli "students"
    private static final String TABLE_STUDENTS = "students",
            COLUMN_STUDENT_ID = COLUMN_DEPARTMENT_ID,
            KEY_FIRSTNAME = "imie",
            KEY_SURNAME = "nazwisko",
            KEY_INDEKS = "indeks",
            KEY_EMAIL = "email",
            KEY_NUMER = "numer";`

Comment: No, you cannot make two columns with the same name in sqlite

Comment: but I need two columns with id of students and id of students for departments

Comment: Okay, what you have to do is use `id` for the id of students and `id_department` for the id of student's department..... Okay...?

Comment: in the student's table

Comment: like this? `// pola tabeli "wydzial"
    private static final String TABLE_DEPARTMENTS = "departments",
            COLUMN_DEPARTMENT_ID = "dep_id",
            KEY_DEPARTMENT = "wydzial",
            KEY_SPECIALIZATION = "kierunek";
    // pola tabeli "students"
    private static final String TABLE_STUDENTS = "students",
            KEY_WYDZIAL = COLUMN_DEPARTMENT_ID,
            COLUMN_STUDENT_ID = "stud_id",
            KEY_FIRSTNAME = "imie",
            KEY_SURNAME = "nazwisko",
            KEY_INDEKS = "indeks",
            KEY_EMAIL = "email",
            KEY_NUMER = "numer";`

Comment: yea, it's working but column KEY_WYDZIAL it's empty :( it's not getting id of department

Comment: @pank_94, I edited the answer again, see how I add the department id in the above method...This will work for you InshaAllah

Comment: yea it's pretty work. I have another question for you.
How can I retrieve ID of the department which is existing in department table and put into student tabel ?

Comment: You need to make a query to retrieve the id of the department from the student id

Comment: I need to retrieve the ID of the department which is existing in department table.

I'm choosing department from the Spinner. The Spinner retrieves the ID of department. And I need to put this retrieved ID to the student table.

Comment: Now you are going to complex :) , basically you need to use the bean concept to retrieve the complete bean(everything related with the department table) of every department from database and then make the spinner's adapter from it...! In this way, you don't need to retrieve the department's id at any point of the form

Comment: One morething, please mark the answer as correct as it helped you...!